# How to debug socket resets in C

Tags: c, sockets, freebsd

I have some code that establishes a connection to servers. For a while, my code runs normally and everything works fine.

At some point though, when trying to connect out, my application sends a SYN flag , gets a SYN/ACK, and then will start sending a FIN flag which terminates the connection!

This is using FreeBSD 9. I have checked all of the limits, and as far as I can tell, I am not exceeding any open socket limits or anything, and I would have not exected the socket to open to even send the SYN flag if it was something like that going on.

What else can I do to debug this? After it happens for one outbound connection, it starts happening for all of them, so I think it must be some kind of systemic problem.

Comment: For starters, you could check if any of the I/O function calls fail and check `errno`.

Comment: Are you implementing some handshake protocol? Or are you watching the traffic (i.e. `tcpdump`, `wireshark`, or otherwise) to know you received SYN/ACK?

Comment: It is TCP , and I am just watching the traffic with tcpdump

Comment: What's the server you're connecting to? Is it your code on another BSD box or something else?

Comment: Could be anything - internet box, whatever

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely to be a coding whoops than some complicated, sinister networking issue. I agree with netcoder, check your calls, check your return values. Check that you're not doing something daft, like eating file descriptors! Check your firewalls at both ends, I've seen that effect with a firewall getting overly protective before. Or post some code for us to look at...

Comment: I will take a look again. I do have checks on most all of the I/O operations as well as the opening/closing of socket descriptors so I was actually leaning toward some complicated sinister networking issue.